# SQL SELECT WHERE Statement

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am querying some data between two Excel Workbooks. the source sheet has two columns 'Responsible Manager' and 'Responsible Supervisor' that I need to filter on. The filter needs to be the same two names for both, so include rows WHERE

- Responsible Manager is Name1 or Name2

**OR**

- Responsible Supervisor is Name1 or Name2

I am struggling with the SQL logic, the string below returns Less rows than expected, suggesting something is incorrect.

```
"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A4:I10000] WHERE (`Responsible Manager`='Name1' OR `Responsible Manager`='Name2') OR (`Responsible Supervisor`='Name1' OR `Responsible Supervisor`='Name2')"
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks
Calico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use square braces instead of quotes for your field names. Like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A4:I10000] WHERE ([Responsible Manager]='Name1' OR [Responsible Manager]='Name2') OR ([Responsible Supervisor]='Name1' OR [Responsible Supervisor]='Name2')"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It would seem I was being foolish... and queriying and old version of the sheet! Hence why the expected number of results wasn't appearing. Both brackets and single quote seem to work.